# How to override default maven-install-plugin behavior?

Tags: maven, overriding, default

I'm need of custom artifact installation and can't figure how to override the default one (from default maven lifecycle). So my question is:

How to configure maven install plugin in my pom.xml so it doesn't do default install and executes just my custom install-file goals?

I tried without id and with [default-install](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html) id and it didn't help.

**Update:** 
From the provided answer - this does not work for me (I see two install attempts in log).

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>default-install</id>
          <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>install-jar-lib</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>install-file</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <configuration>
          <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</file>
          <generatePom>false</generatePom>
          <pomFile>pom.xml</pomFile>
          <packaging>jar</packaging>
          <version>${unicorn.version}</version>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Using `default-<goal>` as the execution ID has worked for me before.  Do you have a global configuration block defined for the install plugin, or are you by chance inheriting from a parent POM that has a global config block?

Comment: Can you post the relevant pom snippet that did not work?

Comment: This solution works but only with as of Maven version 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have the default install skipped if you have at least version 2.4 of the install plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then you can bind another plugin (the ant run plugin or anything else) to this phase by adding

```
 <phase>install</phase>
```

to the execution section of the plugin, and you can run the new install process with

```
 mvn install
```

Answer (score 12):

To disable `maven-install-plugin`:

```xml
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

and for execution of your custom installation goal:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>yourGroupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>yourArtifactId</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>custom-install</id>
          <phase>install</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>yourGoal</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: This solution works with `maven-install-plugin v2.3.1`.

Comment: The `<phase>install</phase>` part on the *custom-install* execution is **important**. Do not assume that by using an install plugin (e.g. additional execution of `maven-install-plugin`) that it will run by default on the install phase.