# Mechanics of Goal execution in Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I have the **wsimport** plugin in my project.

I would like to execute the wsimport. According to the website, the string to execute is **"mvn jaxws:wsimport"**.

Firstly, is this string deductable from the XML ?

The artifact ID is :

```
<artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

and goal :

```
<goal>wsimport</goal>
```

so is the artifact-part just the substring of the artifactid leading up to "-maven-plugin" ?

..And when I execute my plugin goal "mvn jaxws:wsimport" does this completely ignore which phase I am in? Ie. is this running outside of the phase? And if no, is there a way to run this standalone?

ie. is there a way I can set the phase to none? (eg [phase]none[/phase]).

Pom code :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>                    
                <execution>
                    <id>wsimport-from-jdk</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${tool.wsimport}</executable>
                        <wsdlUrls>
                            <wsdlUrl>http://WorkPC:8080/server-web/AirlineWS?wsdl</wsdlUrl>     
                        </wsdlUrls>
                        <packageName>com.bluewalrus</packageName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I sort of answered my question. I had to write down my thoughts on my website : http://blue-walrus.com/2014/03/maven-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

When you issue a command like `mvn [plugin]:[goal]`, it launches Maven out of any lifecycle, so if you do not intend to perform that goal inside a lifecycle, but only via such commands, you shouldn't have any `<execution>` defined, just place `<configuration>` right after `<version>`.
About how Maven can shorten the plugin call (i.e. `mvn dependency:tree` instead of `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree`), it is based on several conventions:

1. When no version defined, it tries to take the latest from available repositories
2. When the groupId is omitted, it looks among the predefined or user-defined *pluginGroups* to find a suitable one. [See here for more information](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html) (Configuring Maven to Search for Plugins)
3. On the same page, you can see how plugins prefixes are used to shorten the plugin prefix, by using a prefix instead of the artifactId of the plugin. Thirdparty plugins should use [prefix]-maven-plugin construction, and it looks OK here.
4. And to disable the default execution of a plugin (although it might not be useful in this case), [you can use this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307343/how-to-override-default-maven-install-plugin-behavior)